# Spring Roo: Showing and downloading a document

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I added a document entity to my application. Applicant entity has a One-to-Many relation with document, i.e. an applicant can upload many documents. I'm still not able to show this document in my app. I want to be able to show the document and download it when the user clicks on the document's link.
I tried to implement the code [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-roo-save-read-blob-object-spring-roo-tutorial/) but the result was a window with a 404 error (description The requested resource is not available).
I'm using MySQL as database.

Here is the rest of my code

Applicant.java

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Applicant {

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String phone;

    /**
     */
    private String address;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String nationality;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    /**
     */
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "applicant")
    private Set<Document> files = new HashSet<Document>();
}
```

Document.java

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Document {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Document.class);

    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private byte[] content;

    @Transient
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String url;

    private String filename;

    private Long size;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 30)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 500)
    private String description;

    private String contentType;

    /**
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "applicant_id")
    private Applicant applicant;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar challenge some weeks ago. I just generated an application with another code generator ([generjee](http://www.generjee.com)). It generates well working One-To-Many document upload/download, if you select the "Enable upload file attachments" checkbox of an entity. Then I copied the document upload/download/show code from it into my spring roo project. Worked fine.
Don't forget to define commons-fileupload in the pom.xml and if you use PrimeFaces, you must set the PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter in web.xml. It's all in the generjee produces code. Just copy&paste.

Comment: Great!!
But I have some more questions. I noticed that there is no 1-to-1 relation, how can I achieve that?
And after generating the code, how can I import it in STS and test it on Tomcat server? If this is not possible, where should I paste the generated classes, because I found some classes and packages that are not generated when creating projects with roo.

Comment: It depends on the project structure you have. Whan I did: (1.) Copy the following methods from OrderBean.java in to your roo-generated Bean: getOrderAttachments(), handleAttachmentUpload(), getAttachmentStreamedContent() and deleteAttachment(). Of course, replace "Order" by your entity name. (2.) Copy the OrderService.java into your project and adapt it. (3.) Copy the OrderAttachment.java into your project and adapt it. (4.) Copy the relevant stuff from order.xhtml and orderAttachmentInclude.xhtml into your project and adapt it.